# Calling class instance as a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Assuming I have a class

```js
class foo {
  constructor() {
    this._pos = 0;
  }
  
  bar(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
  }
}

const obj = new foo();
```

How do I make it possible to call:

```
let var1 = obj('something');
```

Comment: You can't "call" a plain object; what would that even mean? What code would run?

Comment: Do you want to call `bar` method of `foo` class or what? Please clarify.

Comment: What you have and what you want to do don't go with each other. You have an instance of a class (an object) and you want to invoke the object as a function.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/class

Comment: essentially when you `new` something, it returns an object. and you can't invoke an object.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: `obj.bar('something')` will work though

Comment: Technically you could extend built-in `Function` constructor using `class Foo extends Function`. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ch78hx88/) But you can doesn't mean you should. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a callable object by extending the `Function` constructor, though if you want it to access the instance created, you'll actually need to create a bound function in the constructor that binds the instance to a function that is returned.

```js
class foo extends Function {
  constructor() {
    super("...args", "return this.bar(...args)");
    this._pos = 0;
    return this.bind(this);
  }
  
  bar(arg) {
    console.log(arg + this._pos);
  }
}

const obj = new foo();

let var1 = obj('something ');
```

Comment: A very elegant solution! Thank you!